# Time complexity of Data Structures

Tags: c++, data-structures, big-o

I was going over [this page](http://bigocheatsheet.com/):

[image]

And I had the following questions:

1. Does Insertion and Deletion in this table mean insertion and deletion at the end only?
2. For Basic Array, why is insertion and deletion for average and worst case marked as `-`?
3. What does Indexing mean in the table? Does it mean Accessing?
4. Why is Insertion and Deletion of Dynamic Array O(n)?
5. Why is the index of Linked List O(n) while that of Dynamic Array O(1)? Is it because Dynamic Array is continuous and could be accessed directly by pointer arithmetic, while for a linked list a linear search would be needed?

Comment: Keep in mind that asking multiple questions either leave answers not answering all of them, which leave answers split all over the page, as opposed to the 'best' answer being at the top, or users may answer all questions, but some incorrectly, and an answer being half-right, half-wrong obviously doesn't fit well into a linear voting system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Does Insertion and Deletion in this table mean insertion and deletion at the end only?

   **No. Those reflect random insertion and deletion.**

---

2. For Basic Array, why is insertion and deletion for average and worst case marked as `-`?

   **Because "Basic Array" is a static array structure. You cannot insert or delete elements.**

---

3. What does Indexing mean in the table? Does it mean Accessing?

   **It means: to access by index (position) as opposed to access by key (element value).**

---

4. Why is Insertion and Deletion of Dynamic Array O(n)?

   **Because insertion/deletion may require that the array grows or shrinks in length. This may involve copying (all) elements. Therefore O(N).**

---

5. Why is the index of Linked List O(n) while that of Dynamic Array O(1)? Is it because Dynamic Array is continuous and could be accessed directly by pointer arithmetic, while for a linked list a linear search would be needed?

   **Yes.**

Comment: you stated `... as opposed to access by key` by key do you mean pointer ?

Comment: No. Key = Element value

Comment: I think 4) is wrong. Since indexing is O(1), then the cost is most likely from having to copy elements over. Think of `std::vector` rather than `std::list`.

Comment: Now I am a bit confused .. how is indexing of Dynamic Array O(1) ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Dynamic array is a continuous array in which each element is stored in sequence. So to look up a value by index (position) is simple to access the array at that index (position). Hence, O(1).

Comment: @Rajeshwar It is just like an array under the hood, so you can get an element by taking the address to the first one and applying an offset.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Copy elements would not be O(1). That would be O(N).

Comment: @MårtenWikström Yes, that is what I said. It is not O(N) because of "scanning the entire array to find the element...". That step is O(1). Moving elements after that is O(N).

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes if elements needs to be moved. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Scanning is not O(1) though. It's O(N) too. (Unless deletion is by position, in which case there is no scanning at all)

Comment: @MårtenWikström OK, the question is not completely unambiguous, but I had assumed it meant insertion and deletion in nth position, so there is no scanning involved, just an O(1) look-up for that position, followed by an O(N) operation to remove the element while maintaining the structure's invariants.

Comment: "Because insertion/deletion may require that the array grows or shrinks in length. This may involve copying (all) elements. Therefore O(N)." In fact the cost of moving elements while growing and shrinking the array can be amortized, so insertions and deletions at the end are still amortized O(1). The problem is rather that if you insert/delete into/from the middle, you need to move half the elements on average

Answer (score 1):

For 4, when you insert or delete an element into or from a D-array, you should indicate the index to insert or delete, so you need to make some elements moving forward or backward